I get random very loud noises blaring through all audio when listening to something
I use Ubuntu Budgie 24.04 (former Chromebook with Chrome OS). I have an issue with my audio. Mostly whenever I'm listening to something a large audio that goes on for a minute cuts all other audio out and blares a large beep noise.oddly enough if i attach headphones/earphones the noise isn't present anymore.
08
I thought it was because I have low storage, but I can't fix that either because I haven't installed root yet. Now I don't have the storage too, so I can't uninstall packages. I tried rebooting the computer, but that doesn't help either. Is there a way to factory reset the device while only keeping Ubuntu without root?
Device details:


The sound works through the headphones and earbuds, so the sound isn't the issue. The issue is with the speakers. This could be due to a faulty mechanical connection to the speakers. To test the speakers, what happens if you run an Ubuntu live session from the bootable USB flash drive that you used to install Ubuntu? Does the sound from the speakers work OK in an Ubuntu live session?

yes it does work this issue only started a while ago but i think it might be the kernel.

That a kernel update might be the culprit is an excellent guess! If (or when) you have solved this problem please post an answer to your own question.
